# C - casting function call return values to void

Tags: c

In our source code there are function calls like these where the return value gets cast to `void`:

```
(void) pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```

What's the purpose of this?

Comment: Another duplicate that I found a bit better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035927/need-for-prefixing-a-function-with-void

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a functionality or anything. It is just an easy way to document or show the future coders or maintainers that the return value is ignored and the coder was aware of that. Nothing else except this.

<sup>Some function's (applying `warn_unused_result` attribute for gcc) enforce warning on ignoring implicitly the return value - this warning can be suppressed using `void` casting. (On some compiler versions `(void)`cast alone won't do - but that's different story)</sup>

Comment: This also might suppress warning. Some function are marked with compiler-specific attributes to enforce warning if return value is ignored implicitly.

Comment: @Ivan.: yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't have to do this.

Most of the time it is done because you know that a value is returned and to show that to other developers working on the project.